# How to customize my log4j2.xml parameters

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I'm new to using `log4j 2`. I just started, and prepared the following `log4j2.xml` configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%msg%n" />
        </Console>
        <File name="MyFile" fileName="manager.log" immediateFlush="true" append="false">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
            <AppenderRef ref="MyFile"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

What is the default logging behavior and file size in my xml? Is it rolling file, or once per day, or just a single huge file that grows a default size?!

If not, how can I change it to 2 rolling files with max of 10mb?

Comment: What [research](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/) have you done? Have you read the [log4j2 manual](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/)?

Comment: Yes. This code above is my research outcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [File appender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#FileAppender) doesn’t have rollover behavior, it just appends to the specified file. When `append = "false"`, it will overwrite any existing file when the application is restarted.

The [Rolling File Appender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender) is probably what you’re looking for.

The manual has many examples, but this may be close to what you have in mind:

```
1   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
2   <Configuration status="warn" name="MyApp" packages="">
3     <Appenders>
4       <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="logs/app.log"
5                    filePattern="logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
6         <PatternLayout>
7           <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
8         </PatternLayout>
9         <Policies>
10          <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
11          <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB"/>
12        </Policies>
13        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="2"/>
14      </RollingFile>
15    </Appenders>
16    <Loggers>
17      <Root level="error">
18        <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
19      </Root>
20    </Loggers>
21  </Configuration>
```

Comment: So how big in size will the default file (my code) get?

Comment: There’s no limit, depends on how much your application logs. If the application is never restarted it may run out of disk space eventually.

Comment: oh I see! Then I have to switch to your code! Thanks.

Comment: One question: Why there is still a parent app.log?! I get this as well as the two rolling files.

Comment: The app.log file is what Log4j is currently writing to. If a rollover condition is met, Log4j will “roll over” the current file (rename, move to other directory and compress it). It will then create a new “current log file” to append log events to.

Comment: hi is there any ways not to save 2 files per day? I need a maximum 2 files all the time. I tried removing the date from filename, but got error: `filePattern="logs/app-%i.log"`